# Looking for a great scifi book i read as a kid

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in junior high about these cadets in a space academy of some kind.  The main character had purple skin. But the most unique thing about it was a crystalline, psychic entity that is normally deadly, but this person survived it somehow. It really was an amazing book. It's just been so long. I read over 1,200 books in Jr high.

Comment: When was this? 80s? 90s? You say you were in junior high but since we don't know how old you are that doesn't help!

Comment: Welcome to SF&F.SE!  This is a good start to a question.  The more information you give us, the more likely it is that we can help you.  Please edit in anything you remember -- character names, plot details, what made it an 'amazing' book?    Take a look at [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/59154) for ideas of what to add.